# How to dynamically split an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array of strings, sort of like this:

```
["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"]
```

And I need to split the array for every X, Y, and Z or other special keywords there are.

I've tried to split arrays with `[x,y,z].split(y)`, but I'm pretty sure `split()` is only for strings.

The keywords (***x***, ***y***, and ***z***) have to be the first ones in the array.
How can I do this?

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
[
    ["x", "foo"],
    ["y", "bar", "baz"],
    ["z", "0"]
]
```

Comment: do you have a set of keys, or an array which order is important?

Comment: @DexieTheSheep Is the order of array important(x,y,z) important?

Comment: The order is important. This is used for an interpreter for a language that I'm working on, so it usually matters which order you type stuff in.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're writing your own lexer? It's probably the least interesting part of most languages, so you might want to just use one that's already available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could take an array and a closure over the index for the key strings and push an empty array if a key is found.

```js
var array = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"],
    keys = ["x", "y", "z"],
    result = array.reduce((i => (r, s) => {
        if (s === keys[i]) {
            r.push([]);
            i++;
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(s);
        return r;
    })(0), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I didn't think the OP needs the `keys` to appear in order, do they? And even if they did, the closure is horribly confusing. Either put the `i` variable in the outer scope, or if you like functional programming, thread it through in the accumulator.

Comment: @Bergi, op needs the keys in order, as one comment shows.

Comment: I thought that was referring to the order of the result array, i.e. that the property `concat(result) == input` holds.

Answer (score 6):

```
 const keywords = new Set(["x", "y", "z"]);

 let acc = [];
 const result = [];

 for(const el of array) {
   if(keywords.has(el)) {
     result.push(acc = [el]);
   } else acc.push(el);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm too late, but I will show a totally different approach from other answers. In this approach the input array is converted to string using `join()` and the result is obtained using, mainly, regular expressions with the `split()` method:

```js
const input = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
const keyRegex = /(?=#x#)|(?=#y#)|(?=#z#)/;

let res = ("#" + input.join("#") + "#")          // #x#foo#y#bar#baz#z#0#"
    .split(keyRegex)                             // [#x#foo, #y#bar#baz, #z#0#]
    .map(str => str.split("#").filter(Boolean));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

And here is another approach using `map()` over an array with the `keys`. Note I have passed a copy of `input` array to the `map` method and I used it as the `this` argument. Also, I'm using `splice()` over `this` to remove the already analyzed section and perform futures `findIndex()` over a shortened array. However, none of this things can be better than a solution with `reduce()` or a standard `loop` over the input array.

```js
const input = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
const keys = ["x", "y", "z"];

let res = keys.map(function(k, i)
{
    let a = this.findIndex(x => x === k);
    let b = this.findIndex(x => x === keys[i+1]);
    return this.splice(a, b >= 0 ? b : this.length);
}, input.slice());

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way to do it. You could use `slice`:

```js
var a = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
var breakpoints = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var res = [];
for(var i = 0; i < breakpoints.length - 1; i++) {
  res = res.concat([a.slice(a.indexOf(breakpoints[i]), a.indexOf(breakpoints[i+1]))]);
}
res = res.concat([a.slice(a.indexOf(breakpoints[i]))]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a short alternative to the good answers that were already posted, if that can help.

This is using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const input = ['x', 'foo', 'y', 'bar', 'baz', 'z', '0'];
const keywords = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const result = input.reduce((result, value) => {
  keywords.includes(value) ? result.push([value]) : result[result.length - 1].push(value);
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Note that it will fail if the first item in the input array isn't a keyword (which it shouldn't be). You can easily change the condition to `keywords.includes(value) || keywords.length === 0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Using a double reduce is possible on the first stage compute the indexes of each key and on the second reduce split the array:

```js
var arr = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
var keys = keys = ["x", "y", "z"];

var retVal = arr.reduce(function(acc, ele, idx) {
    if (keys.indexOf(ele) > -1) {
        acc.push(idx);
    }
    return acc;
}, []).reduce(function(acc, ele, idx, a) {
    acc.push(arr.slice(ele, a[idx+1]));
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(retVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by this code:

```
function separator(a) {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var index = a[i].trim().toLowerCase();

    switch (index) {
      case "x":
      case "y":
      case "z":
        if (result[index] == undefined) {
          result.push([index]);
        }
        break;

      default:
        result[result.length - 1].push(a[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Sample:
var arr = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
console.log(separator(arr));

// Result must be:
// [["x", "foo"], ["y", "bar", "baz"], ["z", "0"]]
```

Or use this for grouping:

```
function separator(a) {
  var result = {};
  var lastIndex = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var index = a[i].trim().toLowerCase();

    switch (index) {
      case "x":
      case "y":
      case "z":
        if (result[index] == undefined) {
          result[index] = [];
        }
        lastIndex = index;
        break;

      default:
        result[lastIndex].push(a[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Sample:
var arr = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
console.log(separator(arr));

// Result must be:
// {"x": ["foo"], "y": ["bar", "baz"], "z": ["0"]}
```

The second code can works on advanced array like this:

```
["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "x", "baz", "z", "0", "y", "bar2"]

And result is this:
{"x": ["foo", "baz"], "y": ["bar", "bar2"], "z": ["0"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` to extract the individual array by the index of the given keys and push it into the final array.

```js
const arr = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
function splitByKeys(...keys){
let splitarr = [];
  for(let i =0; i<keys.length;i++){
   if(i == keys.length -1 ){
     splitarr.push(arr.slice( arr.indexOf(keys[i]) , arr.length));
   }else{
    splitarr.push(arr.slice( arr.indexOf(keys[i]) , arr.indexOf(keys[i+1])));
   }
  }
  return splitarr;
}
console.log(splitByKeys("x", "y", "z"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = ['x', 'foo', 'y', 'bar', 'baz', 'z', '0'];
const keywords = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

input.reduce((prev, val) => {
    const split = keywords.includes(val);
    const index = prev.length - Number(!split);
    prev[index] = split ? [val] : prev[index].concat(val)
    return prev;
}, []);
```

It's a functional way to do the split and avoid undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 1):

*Pretty simple!*

```js
const arr = ["x", "foo", "y", "bar", "baz", "z", "0"];
const specialChar = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
let result = [];

arr.forEach((el, index) => {
  if(specialChar.includes(el)){
    result.push([el, arr[index + 1]])
  }
});

console.log(result)
```